# What is causing this error: AttributeError: module 'pyNSRDB' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to run code in a terminal via VS Code.  This code should allow me to pull data from the National Solar Radiation Database.  I've obtained a key from them and include that key where "My Key" is written.  I'm not sure if including my actual API key would violate the terms and conditions I agreed to when I applied for it, but anyone can get one for free.

Here is my code:

```
import pyNSRDB
import requests

# Set your NSRDB API key
api_key = "My Key"

# Create a pyNSRDB client
client = pyNSRDB.Client(api_key)
# Get solar radiation data for a specific location and time period
data = client.get_data(
    latitude=43.0727,
    longitude=-89.3880,
    start_date="2023-10-18",
    end_date="2023-10-18",
    data_type="solar",
    variables="ghi,dni,dhi",
)

# Print the solar radiation data
print(data)
```

- I've tried running this code in a local environment as well as in my global environment.
- I have all required packages installed and verified with pip.
- I can't find detailed documentation on pyNSRDB.  I have not yet tried emailing the author.
- Google Bard says the code works for them when they run it.  Their suggestions were to make sure I have everything properly installed on my end, which I've done.
- ChatGPT and Bing Chat both gave me the same troubleshooting advice, which hasn't resolved the issue.

I would appreciate anyone's assistance on this.

Comment: It appears there is a newer version of pyNSRDB that isn't available on PyPI.  Google Bard is running the newer version, while I'm running the latest and outdated one available on PyPI. This is likely the issue.  I will work on finding the new version, but will leave this question up just in case someone else has the same issue.

Comment: This is the GitHub repo for the latest version: https://github.com/bwilliams2/pyNSRDB